# CSS and Label Input alignment vs. tables

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
First Name: Textbox 
Last Name: Textbox 
... 
more labels with unknown widths: more text boxes
```

- Using a table it's dead easy to accomplish this
- Using CSS is also dead easy, for as long as you somehow indicate the
  width of the label(either  percentage or hard coded)
- Using jquery to re-calculate the max width and assign it to all
  labels is also easy

**Problem** None of the above is elegant.

I want a generic CSS that  I can use across all of my websites, where I can display a right aligned group of labels for my inputs and if later the text for one of my label is changed I don't have to redeploy my entire code just to change a darn width value

Something like:

```
<div class="labelInputArea">
    <label for="userName" class="lable">User Name:</label>
    <input name="userName" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div class="labelInputArea">
    <label for="password" class="lable">Password:</label>
    <input name="password" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div class="labelInputArea">
    <label for="longText" class="lable">Some Long Label:</label>
    <input name="longText" type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

and in my .css I would have something like:

```
.labelInputArea 
{
    display:block;
}
.labelInputArea .label
{
    text-align:right;
    display:inline;
}

.labelInputArea input
{
    text-align:left;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) framework, but skin it to your own needs?

Comment: Well, Bootstrap is a front-end framework (aka CSS with implemented javascript). They make stuff like this (especially scalable sizing) really easy. You don't have to go with their look, though. You can change the files around (i.e., make it so the `danger` class is pink, not red) to fit your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you essentially are after a table layout without using tables..
In which case, just using CSS table-row/table-cell styles could work:

```
.labelInputArea 
{
    display:table-row;
}
.labelInputArea label
{
    text-align:right;
    display:table-cell;
}

.labelInputArea input
{
    text-align:left;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/x5c8N/

For what it's worth, I'd probably stick with a fixed width label that will wrap it's contents, eg

```
.labelInputArea 
{
    display:block;
    padding-top:5px;
}
.labelInputArea label
{
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.labelInputArea input
{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4xzF/1/

as I prefer a design that uses vertical space over horizontal space, but that's just my preference :)

Comment: display:table-row, display:table-cell works like a charm; in case you're worried about browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/css-table

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to *auto-adjust* the labels, I don't see any problem with your code. It should adjust depending on the size of your text because you didn't set the width. The only problem that I can think of is that you accidentally set its width somewhere. Try setting it to this:

```
.labelInputArea .lable
{
  width: auto !important;
}
```

the ***!important*** should override the width of the said class.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. if you try my code in a simple <html><body></body></html> page you'll see why not. the text boxes are not aligned; "auto" doesn't adjust the width of all labels based on the one with the max size; you'll need jquery to do that, which is fine; I think display:table-row, display:table-cell does the magic beautifully, though